# django url parameters into context_processor

Tags: django, django-urls, django-context

I have this Django Url:

```
url( r'^(?P<language>.*)/(?P<shop>.*)/(?P<brand>.*)/$', 'app.views.view_1' ),
```

Now, "language", "shop", "brand" are all parameters into my url and I want to read them into my custom Django Context Processor. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing! I've no idea... I searched on Google, I red Django docs... but now I've no idea...

Answer (score 7):

You can access `request.resolver_match` from the context processor. 
This will give you access to the resolved url parameters in `request.resolver_match.kwargs`

Answer (score 0):

I just tell you the idea here. When the url calls `view_1` function , you have language, shop, brand values ... here why don''t you set that values into `session` and get that values in `Context Processor` using `session` variable ..

Comment: The call chain (correct me if I'm in wrong) is: url -> context_processor -> view_1. So, how and where can I set session attributes (language, shop, etc...)? Thanks